# Is there a procedure one can use to design their own hash function library?

Tags: c#, dll, hash

I am trying to find steps to use in order to build a hashing library in C#. I am aware there are options out there but I’m trying to understand how it is engineered and learn how to design my own. Any references will be very appreciated!

Comment: Questions asking us to locate an external resource, tutorial, documentation, software library etc for you are not on topic for SO, sorry. As commentary I would note that a hashing function can be anything you imagine, but the better implementations provide a very low likelihood that two different objects in the problem domain will produce the same hashed identifier

Comment: Impossible to help without knowing what you already know and what you don't.  Have you any advanced mathematical background?  That's probably a place to start.

Comment: See : [Universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).  If you don't understand the math on that page, your first step is to forget about programming and learn the math first.